# REACT как объект пришедший в ответе на метод POST добавить в существующий список объектов и отрисовать его?

Tags: reactjs, post, объекты, get, axios

у меня есть 2 компонента

компонент items делает GET запрос в ответ получает массив (тоже называется items)с объектами и отрисовывает их

```
const client = Axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    client.get("?userId=1").then((response) => {
      setItems(response.data);
    });
  }, [setItems])


return (
    <div className={style.items}>
      <AddButton
        HandlerHeading={HandlerHeading}
        HandlerText={HandlerText}
        PostData={PostData}
      />
      {items.map((item) => (
        <div className={style.items__container} key={item.Id}>
          <h1 className={style.items__heading}>{item.title}</h1>
          <NavLink
            className={style.items__link}
            to={`/CurrentCard/${item.id}`}
            key={item.Id}
          >
            Подробнее...
          </NavLink>
          <p className={style.items__paragraph}>{item.body}</p>
          <button
            className={style.items__btn}
            onClick={() => deletePost(item.id)}
          >
            &times;
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

и так же есть компонент addButton который открывает модальное окно с 2я инпутами
и текст из этих инпутов надо добавить в  массив items тем самым создав новый элемент который надо отрисовать

```
const HandlerHeading = (event) => {
    setHeading(event.target.value);
  };

  const HandlerText = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };


 return (
    <div>
      <a href="#123" className={style.button} onClick={(e) => setOpen(!open)}>
        Add post
      </a>
      {open && (
        <div className={style.button__openContainer}>
          <div className={style.button__inputBox}>
            <input
              className={style.button__inputs}
              onInput={HandlerHeading}
              placeholder="Heading?"
            />
            <input
              className={style.button__inputs}
              onInput={HandlerText}
              placeholder="Text?"
            />
            <button onClick={(e) => PostData(e)}>Save</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

реализовывает изменения массива функция

```
const PostData = (e) => {
    Axios.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/?userId=1", {
      userId: 1,
      title: heading,
      body: text,
      
    })

      .then(response => setItems((prev) => prev.push(response.data),console.log(items)))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  };
```

проблема в том когда я хочу добавить новый пост консоль выдает ошибку

```
Items.jsx:54 Uncaught TypeError: items.map is not a function
```

но вывод в консоль работает и можно увидеть что данные добавились в массив

```
0: {userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit', body: 'quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur …strum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto'}
1: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: 'qui est esse', body: 'est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehend…aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla'}
2: {userId: 1, id: 3, title: 'ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut', body: 'et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis e…\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut'}
3: {userId: 1, id: 4, title: 'eum et est occaecati', body: 'ullam et saepe reiciendis voluptatem adipisci\nsit … ipsam iure\nquis sunt voluptatem rerum illo velit'}
4: {userId: 1, id: 5, title: 'nesciunt quas odio', body: 'repudiandae veniam quaerat sunt sed\nalias aut fugi…sse voluptatibus quis\nest aut tenetur dolor neque'}
5: {userId: 1, id: 6, title: 'dolorem eum magni eos aperiam quia', body: 'ut aspernatur corporis harum nihil quis provident …s\nvoluptate dolores velit et doloremque molestiae'}
6: {userId: 1, id: 7, title: 'magnam facilis autem', body: 'dolore placeat quibusdam ea quo vitae\nmagni quis e…t excepturi ut quia\nsunt ut sequi eos ea sed quas'}
7: {userId: 1, id: 8, title: 'dolorem dolore est ipsam', body: 'dignissimos aperiam dolorem qui eum\nfacilis quibus…\nipsam ut commodi dolor voluptatum modi aut vitae'}
8: {userId: 1, id: 9, title: 'nesciunt iure omnis dolorem tempora et accusantium', body: 'consectetur animi nesciunt iure dolore\nenim quia a…st aut quod aut provident voluptas autem voluptas'}
9: {userId: 1, id: 10, title: 'optio molestias id quia eum', body: 'quo et expedita modi cum officia vel magni\ndolorib…it\nquos veniam quod sed accusamus veritatis error'}
10: {userId: 1, title: 'новый элемент', body: '1', id: 101}
11: {userId: 1, title: 'новый элемент', body: '1', id: 101}
12: {userId: 1, title: 'новый элемент', body: '1', id: 101}
13: {userId: 1, title: 'новый элемент', body: '1', id: 101}
```

но добавляется сразу 4 элемента

Comment: Скорее всего, вы получаете объект, а у объекта нет свойства map.

Comment: Вы изменяете стейт, когда делаете push в него. А нужно создавать новый объект. Попробуйте делать так: `setItems((prev) => [...prev, response.data])`

Comment: понял спасибо разобрался